# User Permissions after PC Name Change

Tags: 14.04, unity, permissions, groups

I made a mistake on my PC name when i installed 14.04.
I altered the name via the netbios command, but have since run into issues.
Do I need to update my user groups? permissions?

Any advice please

Comment: what kind of issues ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change pc-name after installation you just need to change the host and hostname file under etc directory. I don't understand why did you use `netbios`.

For in depth detail please refer [Question-> How to change pc-name after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523731/change-computer-name-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04)